# Using joblib.Memory to cache data in AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, joblib

Is it possible to cache a function output using joblib.Memory in AWS S3, such as passing a remote link to the `cachedir` paramenter?

e.g.:

```
s3_url = 'https://foo.s3..../folder/cache_folder/project_name/joblib'
from joblib import Memory
memory = Memory(s3_url, verbose=0)

@memory.cache
def my_function(x): return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this libary:

https://github.com/aabadie/joblib-s3

From their documentation:

### Getting the latest code

To get the latest code use git:

```
git clone git://github.com/aabadie/joblib-s3.git
```

### Installing joblibs3

Simply use pip:

```
$ cd joblib-s3
$ pip install -r requirements.txt .
```

### Using joblibs3 to cache computation results in AWS S3

See the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Memory
from joblibs3 import register_s3_store_backend

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register_s3_store_backend()

    # we assume you S3 credentials are stored in ~/.aws/credentials, so no
    # need to pass them to Memory constructor.
    mem = Memory('joblib_cache', backend='s3', verbose=100, compress=True,
                 backend_options=dict(bucket="joblib-example"))

    multiply = mem.cache(np.multiply)
    array1 = np.arange(10000)
    array2 = np.arange(10000)

    result = multiply(array1, array2)
    print(result)
```